# Tkinter CheckButton not working in EXE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder, cx-freeze

I work with Tkinter on spyder python3.6.
In my program I use Tkinter CheckButtons with a command. When I execute my program in Spyder, It works well. But when I generate the EXE using cx Freeze, I'm not able to check the checkbuttons on my interface.
I write this code to illustrate my situation.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root,text="Fichiers excel", padx=5, pady=20)
frame.grid(row=0,sticky='nesw')
cbVar=tk.StringVar()

def fct():
    if cbVar.get() =='':
        cbVar.set('salut')
    else:
        cbVar.set('')
    print(cbVar.get())
cb  = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text="cb",variable=cbVar,command=fct,state=tk.NORMAL)
cb.grid(row=0,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

And my setup code is like this:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("debug.py", base=base)]
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "test",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "test",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Comment: Why aren't you able? Does the program crash? Does it throw an error? Does nothing at all happen?

Comment: There is no error, no crash, and  It works perfectly on spyder. But in the .exe I click on it but nothing happens.

Comment: So, you're saying that you click on them an nothing happens, but otherwise the app works just fine?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the small code i've just shared with you, don't work on .exe as well.

Comment: I tried to run my small program in anaconda prompt, but checkButton don't work; just like when in run it from .exe